# Can I set the asterisk_version string

Tags: asterisk

I am trying various different options of building Asterisk 11 and these will be deployed on various servers. They are all built from the same sources and have what I presume to be some sort of checksum embedded in the version ID (26dd464).

In order to distinguish the various versions of the executable I would like to add my own version number or string on similar. I note that `/usr/src/asterisk/main/version.c` specifies a `const char []` variable `asterisk_version`, but if I manually edit this it gets overwritten as part of the `make` process. Is there a sensible way I could specify some sort of identifying label (e.g. as a parameter passed to `make` or some such)?

Comment: I wish I had an [upvote to offer you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353868/608639). This is one of 3 on-topic Asterisk questions in recent history. Its nice to see some folks following Stack Overflow's rules.

Answer (score 0):

In `/usr/src/asterisk/build_tools/make_version_c` you can specify it. This script overwrites the file you've mentioned (/usr/src/asterisk/**utils**/version.c).